# flutter with Sqflite : The return type 'Null' isn't a 'Future<_>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, dart, sqflite

I have a problem function of Inserted => The return type 'Null' isn't a 'Future<_>', as required by the closure's context

[image]

Comment: Please replace the image with a text-based [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add async to your function.

```
await database.transaction((txn) async { });
```

I would also replace then / catchError inside the function with await and try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

If function use async-await then you have to use Future

`Future<void>` -> function is future and `return null` 
`Future<String>` -> function is future and `return String` as output

In above you can replace `Future<_>` by the return type you expect.
I think you have to return int, it will help to know on which row CRUD operation is performed